# Laravel - Count of items through with belongs to

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

A company can have many delivery dates. A delivery date may have many entries. The Entry model contains

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

public function delivery_date()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(MgDeliveryDate::class,  'mg_delivery_date_id');
}
```

What I want is a count of how many entries each delivery date has for each company. For example, something like

```
$companies = Company->with('delivery_dates', 'delivery_dates.entries')->withCount('delivery_dates.entries')
```

So if my data was

```
Company            Delivery Date          Entry Number
   A                   1/2/2020                1
   A                   1/2/2020                2
   A                   2/2/2020                3
   B                   1/2/2020                4
```

I would get two companies, company A with two delivery dates and a count of 2 for the first date(1/2/2020) and 1 for the second date(2/2/2020) and company B with one delivery date, with an entry count of 1.

Comment: you can join them and group by fields

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Give this a shot.

```
$companies = Company::with('delivery_dates.entries')->get();

$companies->map(function($company){
    return $company->delivery_dates->map(function($delivery){
        return $delivery->entries->count();
    })->groupBy('delivery_date');
});
```

I have used Laravel Collection [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-map) method.

Comment: thanks for your help. At the moment the first step is wrong. I get all the delivery dates for that company which is correct, but then get all the entries for that delivery date, not just ones for that company and delivery date. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

// i am not sure what you actually want.. if you want the data like this then you can try this

```
[
{ company:abc , date:[{1/20} , {2/20} ...] , entry:[{1} ,{2} ...]} , 
{}, 
....
]
```

Company model

```
public function entry()
{
    return $this->hasMany(entry::class);
}

And Then
$companies = Company::withCount(['entry', 'delivery_dates' => function ($query) {
    $query->where(your condition);
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may write:

```
$companies = Compnay::with(['delivery_dates' => function ($q) {
    $q->withCount('entries');
}])
->get();
```

You will get the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yezan, but this will give me all entries for that delivery date, not just the entries for that company. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think so, a `Company` has many `DeliveryDate`and a `DeliveryDate`has many `Entry`. So the query I gave you will load companies with their delivery dates whose on turn contain the entry count of the delivery dates of that particular company.